# Including banners with Iframes effects on SEO?

Tags: iframe, seo

I made a HTML5 banner of my website. I want to host it on my server and provide it to other sites with an Iframe. Is this bad for SEO?

Will the link on the banner as a link pointing to my site? In such case what can I do so it counts towards Google rankins/how else can I include the banner outside my site?

Comment: SEO questions should be on the webmasters SO site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't affect your SEO since iframe aren't search engine friendly. A better way to do this is to use JavaScript to provide the banner and then use `<noscript>` to link back to your website. Then you will benefit from SEO as that link is a positive ranking factor in all search engine algorithms.

Comment: I don't quite understand the method you suggest. My banner is at: `http://mysite.com/banner.php` how can I include it your way?